# Finding Trig Functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am given $$\cos(\beta) = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{8}$$ and I am asked to find the indicated trig function of $$\sin(90^{\circ}- \beta)$$

I know $$\sin(\beta)= \frac{7}{8}$$ but I don't know how to go about finding what the question asks. Could someone please help me?

Comment: cosine is an abbreviation for "compliment's sine". The compliment of $(90^\circ - \beta)$ is $\beta$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$\cos \beta=\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta)$

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thank you so much! Could you explain why that is the same thing?

Comment: Never mind I got it! These are cofunction identities.